# Why 'os.system' exits with return code 1?

Tags: python, windows, adb

I want to execute some adb commands from python script. But when i executed the following line

```
os.system('adb devices')
```

The cmd returns with 1 instead of 0. I also tried executing

```
os.popen('adb devices').read()
```

I am getting empty string. Please help me to solve this.
Note: I tried the same commands from command window and it was working fine. I also added the path of adb.exe to windows PATH environment variable.

Comment: does the `os.system` command give you any output? Maybe an error?

Answer (score 4):

According to Windows [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), you've got 1, because there was an error on your command.

Maybe use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) could be a better approach.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_output(
    "adb devices", 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True)
```