# don't know why os.system code returns 1

Tags: python, os.system

I can't find out why my os.system python code returns 1.

```
import os
flist =  getFileList("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/TM/reports")
a = flist[0].replace('.pdf', '.txt')
os.system("pdf2txt.py -o a flist[0]")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why 'os.system' exits with return code 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807062/why-os-system-exits-with-return-code-1)

Comment: @SeeDart The cause of the error is different,

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant

```
import os
flist =  getFileList("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/TM/reports")
a = flist[0].replace('.pdf', '.txt')
# 1. os.system("pdf2txt.py -o a flist[0]") 
# 2. os.system("pdf2txt.py -o a " + "flist[0]")
os.system("pdf2txt.py -o " + a + " " + '"' + flist[0] + '"')
```

The differences between all 3 options are very subtle. In 1,2 python is executing the command with a string literal `flist[0]` and the other, uncommented option, with the value contained at  `flist[0]`

Comment: And even more, add quotes around flist[0]

Comment: Good idea @ddbug! Edited to add in your comment

Comment: No I did not mean to break the working code :)). Just to quote the filename in case it contains spaces. `+ '"'+flist[0] + '"' `